# Can Truffle deployer send ether on construction?

Tags: truffle

If a contract has a `payable` constructor and needs to be filled on construction, is this possible with the truffle migration workflow?

Answer (score 5):

Found the answer over at truffle's gitter channel:

```
var Web3 = require("../node_modules/web3/");
web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(CONTRACT, "123", {from:web3.eth.accounts[0], value:1000000});
};
```